# How do avoid empty boxes when splitting framed Theorems over two pages

Tags: mdframed, layout, newtheorem

I am working with mdframed and have the following issue:

I am writing some mathematical lecture notes and I am using mdframed for Theorems, Definitions and so on. Sometimes it happens, that the text of some Definition or Theorem has enough space on some page but still there is some additional empty box on the next page.

Here is some explicit Example: (Srry I wasn't able to create some simple example and therefore I just copied an example where it happens explicitely in my text)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=35mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%Layoutstyle: 
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\copyright\,First Name Second Name}

%Structures: Theorems, Definitions, Remarks,...
\usepackage{amsthm}%includes \newtheorem
\usepackage{mdframed}%framed environments
\theoremstyle{definition}%not italic inside environment

\newmdtheoremenv[everyline=true,linewidth=1.1pt,innertopmargin=-2pt, innerbottommargin=7pt]{Definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newmdtheoremenv[everyline=true,linewidth=1.1pt,innertopmargin=-2pt, innerbottommargin=7pt]{Theorem}[Definition]{Theorem}
\newmdtheoremenv[everyline=true,linewidth=1.1pt,innertopmargin=-2pt, innerbottommargin=7pt]{Lemma}[Definition]{Lemma}

%Examples with Black Triangle:
\newtheorem{Examplep}[Definition]{Example}
\newenvironment{Example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacktriangle$}
  \Examplep}{\popQED\endExamplep}



\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{Theorem of Banach-Steinhaus}

\begin{Definition} (Convex Sets)\newline
Let $V$ be a real vector space and $M\subset V$. We call $M$ ``convex'', if $\forall x,y\in M$ and for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$:
\begin{align*}\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in M\end{align*}
\end{Definition}

\begin{Example}\label{BallConvex} Let $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a real normed vector space. Then every ball $B_{r}(z)$ for some $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $z\in X$ is a convex set, because
\begin{align*}\Vert z-(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\Vert=\Vert \lambda (z-x)+(1-\lambda)(z-y)\Vert\leq \lambda r+(1-\lambda)r=r\end{align*}
for all $x,y\in B_{r}(z)$ and for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$.
\end{Example}

\begin{Lemma}\label{LemmaConv1} (Linear Operator preserve Convexity)\newline
Let $V$ and $W$ be two real vector spaces and $T\in L(V,W)$. If $M\subset V$ is convex, then also $T(M)$.\end{Lemma}

\begin{proof}Let $a,b\in T(M)$. Then there is are $x,y\in M$ such that $a=Tx$ and $b=Ty$. Using convexity of $M$, we have that 
\begin{align*}\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b=\lambda T(x) + (1-\lambda)T(y)=T(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\in T(M)\end{align*}find for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$.\end{proof}

\begin{Lemma}\label{LemmaConv2} (Closure of convex set is convex)\newline
Let $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a real normed vector space and $M\subset X$ be a convex set. Then $\overline{M}$ is convex.
\end{Lemma}

\begin{proof}Let $x,y\in\overline{M}$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$. Then there is are sequences $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in M^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n}=y$. We define a sequence $(z_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in M^{\mathbb{N}}$ via 
\begin{align*}z_{n}=\lambda x_{n}+(1-\lambda)y_{n}\end{align*}
It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_{n}=\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$, because
\begin{align*}\Vert z_{n}-z\Vert\leq \lambda\underbrace{\Vert x_{n}-x\Vert}_{\to 0}+(1-\lambda)\underbrace{\Vert y_{n}-y\Vert}_{\to 0}\to 0.\end{align*}
This shows that $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y\in M$.\end{proof}

\begin{Theorem} (of Banach-Steinhaus, Uniform Boundedness Principle)\newline
Let $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{X})$ be a Banach space and $(Y,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{Y})$ be a normed space over the same field $\mathbb{F}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$. Furthermore, let $I$ be an arbitrary index set and $(T_{i})_{i\in I}\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)^{I}$ be a collection of bounded operators from $X$ to $Y$. Then:
\begin{align*}\forall x\in X:\sup_{i\in I}\Vert T_{i}x\Vert_{Y}<\infty\hspace*{1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace*{1cm} \sup_{i\in I}\Vert T_{i}\Vert <\infty\end{align*}
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

The ouput at the end of the first page and the beginning of the second page is the following:

[image]

Does anyone have some ideas how to avoid this empty box on the next page?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to switch to tcolorbox instead

Comment: I have the same problem with mdframed in a lecture note project. We ended up making two version of each theorem env, one allows page breaks the other (default) does not. Yes annoying, but it solved our problem. I don't think tcolorbox has the same issues

Comment: Thanks @daleif for the answer. Thats indeed annoying. I will check out tcoloubox...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by daleif in the comments, tcolorbox is the better choice. You can use the built-in `theorems` library, but you can also wrap an amsthm environment with a tcolorbox using `\tcolorboxenvironment`. Here I define a command `\newboxedtheorem` that calls `\newtheorem` then `\tcolorboxenvironment` with the last argument being the tcolorbox options.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=35mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%Layoutstyle: 
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\copyright\,First Name Second Name}

%Structures: Theorems, Definitions, Remarks,...
\usepackage{amsthm}%includes \newtheorem
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\theoremstyle{definition}%not italic inside environment

\NewDocumentCommand{\newboxedtheorem}{s m o m o m}{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\newtheorem*{#2}{#4}}
    {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}
        {%
          \IfNoValueTF{#5}
            {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}}
            {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}[#5]}
        }
        {\newtheorem{#2}[#3]{#4}}
    }
  \tcolorboxenvironment{#2}{#6}
  }
\tcbset{
  boxthsty/.style={
    colback=white,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=1.1pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    breakable,
    }
  }
\newboxedtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[chapter]{boxthsty}
\newboxedtheorem{Theorem}[Definition]{Theorem}{boxthsty}
\newboxedtheorem{Lemma}[Definition]{Lemma}{boxthsty}

%Examples with Black Triangle:
\newtheorem{Examplep}[Definition]{Example}
\newenvironment{Example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacktriangle$}
  \Examplep}{\popQED\endExamplep}



\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{Theorem of Banach-Steinhaus}

\begin{Definition} (Convex Sets)\newline
Let $V$ be a real vector space and $M\subset V$. We call $M$ ``convex'', if $\forall x,y\in M$ and for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$:
\begin{align*}\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in M\end{align*}
\end{Definition}

\begin{Example}\label{BallConvex} Let $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a real normed vector space. Then every ball $B_{r}(z)$ for some $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $z\in X$ is a convex set, because
\begin{align*}\Vert z-(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\Vert=\Vert \lambda (z-x)+(1-\lambda)(z-y)\Vert\leq \lambda r+(1-\lambda)r=r\end{align*}
for all $x,y\in B_{r}(z)$ and for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$.
\end{Example}

\begin{Lemma}\label{LemmaConv1} (Linear Operator preserve Convexity)\newline
Let $V$ and $W$ be two real vector spaces and $T\in L(V,W)$. If $M\subset V$ is convex, then also $T(M)$.\end{Lemma}

\begin{proof}Let $a,b\in T(M)$. Then there is are $x,y\in M$ such that $a=Tx$ and $b=Ty$. Using convexity of $M$, we have that 
\begin{align*}\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b=\lambda T(x) + (1-\lambda)T(y)=T(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\in T(M)\end{align*}find for all $\lambda\in [0,1]$.\end{proof}

\begin{Lemma}\label{LemmaConv2} (Closure of convex set is convex)\newline
Let $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a real normed vector space and $M\subset X$ be a convex set. Then $\overline{M}$ is convex.
\end{Lemma}

\begin{proof}Let $x,y\in\overline{M}$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$. Then there is are sequences $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in M^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n}=y$. We define a sequence $(z_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in M^{\mathbb{N}}$ via 
\begin{align*}z_{n}=\lambda x_{n}+(1-\lambda)y_{n}\end{align*}
It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_{n}=\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$, because
\begin{align*}\Vert z_{n}-z\Vert\leq \lambda\underbrace{\Vert x_{n}-x\Vert}_{\to 0}+(1-\lambda)\underbrace{\Vert y_{n}-y\Vert}_{\to 0}\to 0.\end{align*}
This shows that $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y\in M$.\end{proof}

\begin{Theorem} (of Banach-Steinhaus, Uniform Boundedness Principle)\newline
Let $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{X})$ be a Banach space and $(Y,\Vert\cdot\Vert_{Y})$ be a normed space over the same field $\mathbb{F}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$. Furthermore, let $I$ be an arbitrary index set and $(T_{i})_{i\in I}\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)^{I}$ be a collection of bounded operators from $X$ to $Y$. Then:
\begin{align*}\forall x\in X:\sup_{i\in I}\Vert T_{i}x\Vert_{Y}<\infty\hspace*{1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace*{1cm} \sup_{i\in I}\Vert T_{i}\Vert <\infty\end{align*}
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]