# Extra information text boxes

Tags: formatting

I would like to add 'extra information text boxes' to my master thesis. I've tried something based on [this post](https://texblog.org/2015/09/30/fancy-boxes-for-theorem-lemma-and-proof-with-mdframed/), but it's not exactly what I want. I would like LaTeX to treat those boxes as figures, keeping them together (not splitting them over different pages) and position them in a place where they suit ('floating'). I've tried different things but I'm quite new to LaTeX and I don't know how to solve this. Can you help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

This is what I've done now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{theo}[chapter]\setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theo}}

\newenvironment{theo}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
{\strut Kader~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
{\strut Kader~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{
backgroundcolor=gray!20,
innertopmargin=\topskip
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[Test]{thm:test}
Extra information ...
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted was unfortunately not compilable (see [how to write an MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/237192)), that's why I started from zero and try to provide you a good starting point so that you will be able to adapt the following code or ask follow-up questions (e.g. in this solution you cannot provide a placement specifier to a single `infobox` like `\begin{infobox}[H]`. This is definitely possible (probably with `\NewDocumentCommand` or the equivalent thing for environments), but if I understoof you correctly you don't need that right now).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,lipsum,tcolorbox}% lipsum is only used for testing reasons.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newfloat{info@box}{tbp}{loi}[section]% 1: Name of float environment. 2: Default placement (top, bottom, ...). 3: File extension if written to an aux-file (like toc, lof, lot, loa, ...). 4: Numbering within <section/subsection/...>.
\makeatother
\floatname{info@box}{Infobox}% Adapt caption.

\newenvironment{infobox}[1][]{% Create new environment using info@box and tcolorbox
   \begin{info@box}%
      \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!15!white,%                    background color
            colframe=red!75!black,%                               frame color
            title=Additional information\ifstrempty{#1}{}{: #1}.% title
         ]%
}{%
      \end{tcolorbox}%
   \end{info@box}%
}

\begin{document}
   \lipsum[1]\par
   \begin{infobox}
      Very interesting information.
      \caption{Even captions are possible!}
   \end{infobox}
   \lipsum[1]\par
   \begin{infobox}[Boxes are nice]
      Very interesting information.
   \end{infobox}
   \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Here both boxes are on top of the page, although they appear later in the code, this means they can float.
[image]

Note: I used `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed` because of [problems at page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590554/237192). See the documentation for setting up your tcolorboxes.